# Refinement of $X=\{a,b,c\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}, T=\{\emptyset,X,\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\}\}$.
Is it correct to say that $\{X\}$ is an open refinement of every open cover of $X$?

Comment: Write out your definition of "open refinement" and see if this meets it.

Comment: @Tyrone, If $X=\{a,b,c\},T=\{ϕ,X,\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\}\}$ then is it correct to say that $\{X\}$ is an open refinitement for every finite open cover?

Comment: No. As Randall suggests, write out the definition of "open refinement". Maybe you should add it to your question and explain why you think the example fail to meet its requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (for the *corrected* question): if $\mathcal{U}$ is any open cover of $X$, it must cover $a \in X$. The *only* open set that contains $a$ is $X$ (it's an "indiscrete" or "fat" point, as it were) and so $X \in \mathcal{U}$ must hold. It follows that $\{X\} \prec \mathcal{U}$ because $X$ is a subset of *some* member of $\mathcal{U}$.

This is quite rare in real life, but a valid exercise in the definition of refinement.

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to write $T=\{\emptyset,X,\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\}\}$. Is $\{X\}$ correct then?